# event listener works in jsFiddle but not on page

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

This Event listener works on jsFiddle, but not when I call it from my PHP page.

```
function addDice() {  
 var add = document.getElementById("add");  
alert("test");      
}  

var el = document.getElementById("add");   
el.addEventListener("click", addDice, false);  

   <li id="add">CAll ADD</li>
```

I have the script in my index page between the `<Script>` tags, If I put an `onclick="addDice"` in the `<li>` tag it works, but not with the `eventListener`.

Comment: Probably you have `onLoad` selected from `Framework` field in jsFiddle, but your page tries to access `#add` before it exists.

Comment: That is what i thought first, but how can I have an body onload without calling the function ?

Comment: here's a simple, great example - toggle class of an element via a separate element: http://jsfiddle.net/UaT3P/115/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    function addDice() {  
        var add = document.getElementById("add");  
        alert("test");      
    }  
    var el = document.getElementById("add");   
    el.addEventListener("click", addDice, false);
}
```

Comment: And there is magic.!
Have been pulling my hair for a bit now. Thank you very much!.

Comment: You've been working with IE5 quirks mode last five years??? :-S

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Me? Yep, the intranet stuff in the company I was working for. Actually it seems I've to update my profile. A new job, no more IE Quirks, now I'm free to use IE8 : ).

Answer (score 2):

your code Run Before #add for That is not work You can solve it Like this

```
window.onload=function(){
         var el = document.getElementById("add");   
         el.addEventListener("click", addDice, false);
}
```

or by JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         var el = document.getElementById("add");   
         el.addEventListener("click", addDice, false);

}) ;
```